# Cassandra cluster configuration for 2 nodes returns error

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to build Cassandra (2.1.5) cluster using 2 nodes (each node is virtual machine - Ubuntu 14.04 on virtual box)

First node config (cassandra.yaml):

cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
initial_token: 3074457345618258602
seed_provider:
    - seeds: "192.168.56.101,192.168.56.102"
listen_address: 192.168.56.101
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160
broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4
endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch

Second node config (cassandra.yaml):

cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
initial_token: 0
seed_provider:
    - seeds: "192.168.56.101,192.168.56.102"
listen_address: 192.168.56.102
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160
broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4
endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch

Starting Cassandra on both nodes I am getting:

INFO  19:28:38 Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042...
INFO  19:28:39 Binding thrift service to /0.0.0.0:9160
INFO  19:28:39 Listening for thrift clients...
INFO  19:28:57 FatClient /192.168.56.103 has been silent for 30000ms, removing from gossip
ERROR 19:29:08 Exception in thread Thread[OptionalTasks:1,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: -1039847426114941815 not found in 
    at org.apache.cassandra.locator.TokenMetadata.getPredecessor(TokenMetadata.java:683) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.locator.TokenMetadata.getPrimaryRangesFor(TokenMetadata.java:627) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SizeEstimatesRecorder.run(SizeEstimatesRecorder.java:68) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$UncomplainingRunnable.run(DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:82) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: It appears gossip is failing, check if both VM can talk to each other, if ports are open